# How to unselect WFS feature using geoextjs2?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

I am using Openalayer 2.12, extjs 4.1 and geoextjs 2. I have created toolbar using geoext js Using [link](http://geoext.github.io/geoext2/examples/action/mappanel_with_actions.html). Now in this link you can find select feature. but i have modified the code as

```
action = Ext.create('GeoExt.Action', {
    tooltip: "select",
    icon: 'Images/sel.png',
    control: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(building),
    map: map,
    // button options
    toggleGroup: "tools",
    enableToggle: true,
    group: "tools",
    handler: function() {
                    //alert("Select the feature");
                    ed=null;
                    sm=1;
                }       

            });

actions["select"] = action;
toolbarItems.push(Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', action));
```

Now this code select the layer building now i want to unselect this selected feature on click of other tool in toolbar and code i have

```
action = Ext.create('GeoExt.Action', {
        tooltip: "Unselect",
        icon: 'Images/unsel.png',
        handler: function() {

                    }       

                }); 
actions["unselect"] = action;
toolbarItems.push(Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', action));
```

Can any one please help me to unselect the feature in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an unselectAll() function in the SelectFeature Control. Here's an example (untested):

```
action = Ext.create('GeoExt.Action', {
    tooltip: "Unselect All",
    icon: 'Images/unsel.png',
    handler: function() {
        selectControls = map.getControlsByClass("OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature")
        for(var i=0; i<selectControls.length; i++) {
            selectControls[i].unselectAll();
        }
    }       
}); 
actions["unselect"] = action;
toolbarItems.push(Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', action));
```